# Use series number as X axis label in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: charts, google-spreadsheets

When you create a line plot chart out of a column in Google Spreadsheet, it has its Y-axis marked with values from the data range, but its X-axis completely unmarked, which makes zero sense:
[image: Note the absense of X-axis labels]

Note the absense of X-axis labels

How do I make Google Spreadsheet auto-number values in the column and present number in series, starting from 1, as X-axis marking?

That's what LibreOffice and Excel do by default:
[image: Note the presense of X-axis labels]

Note the presense of X-axis labels

I understand that I can have additional column with labels for X-axis but that's extra work that obviously should be done by spreadsheet (as Excel and LibreOffice do) so I expect some checkbox somewhere that I didn't see.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and create your own values for X like this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(A:Z))
```

This will create a 1 - 26 values in the row where you will place the formula.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: I don't understand where I should put this formula to. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For example put this formula in A1

and you will have numbers go for every collumn, then you can do it as X for your needs if needed to be used in another formulas

Comment: Still it requires additional setup and isn't easier than just adding an index row manually.